# Python - Preserve excel pivot tables

Tags: python, excel

I am copying an existing file into a new workbook, and then hidding some unnecessary tabs. One of the tabs that needs to be visible contains a pivot table that after the script finishes appears as values (instead of the actual pivot table). I need to "preserve" the pivot table

*Edit: Excel 2013 version*

This is my code:

```
import xlsxwriter
import openpyxl as xl
import shutil

shutil.copy('C:/Prueba/GOOG.xlsm', 'C:/Prueba/GOOG-copia.xlsm')
workbook  = xl.load_workbook('C:/Prueba/GOOG-copia.xlsm', keep_vba = 'True')

keep = ['Cacaca','Sheet1'] # Cacaca contains a pivot table that needs to be preserved

for i in workbook.sheetnames:
    if i in keep:
        pivot = workbook[i]._pivots[0]
        pivot.cache.refreshOnLoad = True
        workbook[i].sheet_state = 'visible'
    else:
        workbook[i].sheet_state = 'hidden'

workbook.save('C:/Prueba/GOOG-copia.xlsm')
workbook.close
```

Error:

```
AttributeError: 'Worksheet' object has no attribute '_pivots'
```

Comment: Have you looked at [the example for how to do this in the documentation](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pivot.html#example)?

Comment: Hi, yes, sorry I should have clarified that. I am just a little unsure of how to apply it to the code as I am still learning

Comment: It's quite clear in the documentation, you just have to cache one of the pivots. Have you even tried to replicate the example in your code?

Comment: Yes, let me edit my post

Comment: I just edited. Thank you for the help by the way, sorry for the noob question

Comment: Can you please verify what worksheet it is that is crashing your code? As in, does `Sheet1` contain a pivot as well? If not, is that the sheet that is crashing?

Comment: Yes, I verified. I think the problem is that literally Worksheets does not have such attribute... despite docs... If you do wb['Cacaca']._ and see what pops up, "_pivots" is not there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pivot.html#example) to preserve a pivot-tables, you have to set at least one their booleans `pivot.cache.refreshOnLoad` to `True`

Due to `_pivots` not existing on a sheet unless it contains an actual pivot-table, we can check for a pivot-table and set the cache if one is found:

```
for i in workbook.sheetnames:
    if i in keep:
        ws = workbook[i]
        if hasattr(ws, "_pivots"):
            pivot = ws._pivots[0]
            pivot.cache.refreshOnLoad = True
        workbook[i].sheet_state = 'visible'
    else:
        workbook[i].sheet_state = 'hidden'
```

Comment: I am just checking out why _pivots attributes is not popping up (i.e., uploading to latest versions and such). Will then try this and mark as right